# Équité, équitabilité?

Tags: vocabulaire, philosophie

Bonjour,
une question me turlupine depuis plusieurs jours, et je n'ai pas trouvé de résultat probant sur internet.

J'aimerais connaitre la nuance entre équité et équitabilité.

Merci d'avance pour vos réponses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On opposera en effet équité à équitable (plutôt qu'à l'équitabilité).

L'équité à un sens moral, des notions de justice.
Équitable fait plus appel à une notion de partage le plus égal possible.

- Distribuer une somme d'argent de manière équitable c'est la partager en parts égales entre les récipiendaires.
- Distribuer une somme d'argent avec équité c'est la répartir en tenant compte des besoin de chacun.

Answer (score 10):

Si on prend les sens «communs» (je me baserai ici sur mon Petit Robert 2007), «équitabilité» n'existe pas. *Équitable* est un adjectifs dérivé (16e siècle) de *équité* (qui date du 13e), et ce mot est le nom qui lui correspond.

Toutefois, *équitable* a acquis un second sens beaucoup moins lié à *équité* que le premier, soit «qui est lié au commerce équitable», en ce sens, j'imagine qu'on peut légitimement parler de l'équitabilité d'un produit. C'est un problème qu'on vois avec *horribilité*: ce qui est **horrible** ne suscite pas nécessairement l'**horreur** à proprement parler, mais si tu emploies *horribilité*, tu risque fort de te faire rabrouer.

Dans les sens plus techniques, l'équitabilité est également un concept mathématique (dans le calcul des probabilité, mais c'est peut-être une mauvaise traduction de l'anglais) et en biodiversité (où il semble signifier *grosso modo* «équivalence»).

Comment: Merci de cette réponse rapide et enrichissante.

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour,
Soyons clairs pour exclure du "bon français" les termes techniques qui créent une confusion, car ils sont parfois des néologismes formés à partir du mot d'origine.  "Equitabilité", comme substantif correspondant à l'adjectif "équitable" (au sens de ce qui est juste, équilibré), n'existe pas, ainsi que cela est indiqué dans la réponse précédente, qui précise à juste titre qu'"équitabilité" est un terme technique utilisé en agronomie notamment. Donc il est à exclure au sens de ce qui est équitable, juste et qui est traduit par le mot "équité".